# How to implement a cache without clock signal in Verilog?

Tags: caching, verilog, cpu-architecture

I'm doing this homework problem of Computer Organization and Design. I need to use Verilog to implement a cache, which connects a CPU and a main memory. The cache should be direct mapped. It should use write back scheme for writing, and LRU for replacement.

The interface of the cache is as follows:

```
module cache(
    input wire          rw,             //from CPU, 1 for write, 0 for read
    input wire[31:0]    addr,           //from CPU, memory address
    input wire[31:0]    wdata,          //from CPU, data to write
    input wire[31:0]    mem_rdata,      //from memory, data read
    input wire          mem_done,       //from memory, r/w done
    output reg[31:0]    rdata,          //to CPU, data read
    output reg          hit_miss,       //to CPU, 1 for r/w hit, 0 for r/w miss
    output reg          mem_rw,         //to memory, 1 for write, 0 for read
    output reg[31:0]    mem_addr,       //to memory, memory address
    output reg[31:0]    mem_wdata       //to memory, data to write
);
endmodule
```

Other interface signals can be added if necessary, but it is specially stated that clock signal and FSM are not needed in the cache implementation.

I find it difficult not to use a clock signal. The cache has internal states, so it is more than just combinational logic. But how can a sequential logic be implemented without clock signal? Thanks very much for any idea.

Comment: That's a weird interface.  Usually, you'll have 2 bits for `rw`, so we can say read, write, do nothing (takes 2 bits to cover that third option of do nothing).  We do not want the cache to perform operations when the instruction is not asking for any memory access, in part because we don't want to change the cache state under those conditions, but also because we don't have any idea whether `addr` is valid then, so might cause false misses, etc..  Maybe that notion is hidden in `mem_done`, but how might we know as we don't have any other documentation on this?

Comment: @ErikEidt Since other interface signals can be added in the problem, an enable signal may be added to avoid false misses.